# Replacing occurrences of generic string

Tags: java, regex

I never was good enough with regex, and I assume this is the job for it.

I have a link like `www.somelink/phoyto.jpg/?sz=50`

I need to replace 50 with my value, let's say 100. Trouble is, that I cannot be sure, that this will be always `sz=50` and not `sz=150` or `sz=10` or any other value.

What I need is to find an occurence of string contains of `'sz' + number` and replace it with `'sz=100'`.

Sure, I can do that 'manually" in some for loop, but that wouldn't be nor smar nor efiicient.

Comment: Just some dumb for loop, since I really suck in regex :/ Wouldnt mention it

Comment: Have you tried a regex tutorial? Are you willing to learn or just looking for a solution to be handed to you? If you're willing to learn, start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ If not, just wait and somebody will spoon-feed you a solution.

Comment: Spoon-feeding was just something I needed right now. I believe somebody will also make use of it

Comment: Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference. One answer that may interest is [validating urls](http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/2736496), which is listed under "Common Validation Tasks". There's also a section of online testers at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str = "www.somelink/phoyto.jpg/?sz=50";
str.replaceall("sz=\\d+", "sz=100");
```

`\d` is the java pattern for digit. `+` stands for one or more digits. `replaceall` replaces all occurrences of `sz=<number>`.

Here is a handy online regex tester for java: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Good explanation, however, the criticism I have about this answer is that the replacement is incorrect according to the question. The replacement is supposed to be `sz100` looking at what was posted; here it's `sz=100` — so which is it? I might suggest stackoverflow.com needs an `incorrect correct answer` button for these scenarios. :D

Comment: The correct answer of SO is from the OP's perspective

Comment: Answer is fully correct, questions has a typo, which I corrected

Comment: syntax error - function name should be "replaceAll"

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
String link = "www.somelink/phoyto.jpg/?sz=50";
link = link.replaceFirst("sz=\\d+", "sz=100");
System.out.println(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, and this pattern should work:

```
(sz=\d+)
```

**Code:**

```
String result = searchText.replaceAll("(sz=\\d+)", "sz100");
```

**Example:**

http://regex101.com/r/mB3xT9